# Is it possible to use a generic inside a generic struct init in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I would like to know if it is possible to use a generic type to initialize another generic. I put a example code below.

```
struct Object: Decodable {
    let id: String?
    let type: String?
}

struct JSON<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let data: T?
}

func test<T: Decodable>(type: T.Type) {
    let dataFromAPI = Data()
    let model = JSONDecoder().decode(JSON<type>, from: dataFromAPI)
}
```

I am receiving this error message:

> Use of undeclared type 'type'

Comment: Is `JSONDecoder().decode(JSON<T>.self, from: dataFromAPI)` what you want?

Comment: I want to use a generic input parameter in my `test()` and use the same parameter to initialize my struct `JSON`, which will use the generic type to set `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call generic type struct then use this:

```
   do {
     let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(JSON<T>.self, from: dataFromAPI)

   } catch let message {
        print("JSON serialization error:" + "\(message)")
   }
```

Or if you want to decode simple struct then:

```
   do {
     let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(Object.self, from: dataFromAPI)

   } catch let message {
        print("JSON serialization error:" + "\(message)")
   }
```

Comment: I think you want `try`, not `try!` inside a `do/catch`.